# drupal credit card security

Tags: security, drupal, transactions, credit-card

what are the best *security features* (settings,modules) provided by **drupal** according to ***credit card transaction***?. Do you have any additional prevention techniques .If possible post important and necessary setting points also please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most importantly, don't handle the CC data *at all*. There are several payment processors which provide a payment API and handle the CC processing for you. That way, you don't need to worry about PCI DSS or about escaped CC#s (and the resulting PR brouhaha) when your database is compromised.

(it may seem I'm dodging the question here, but every time we've done a calculation of costs in process cards ourselves/have a processor do it, the roll-your-own approach would bring high initial costs and considerably higher maintenance costs, plus higher risks. OTOH, payment processor will cost you something, but takes this risk+PCI DSS off you)

Comment: +1. Get a module like Ubercart, and a payment processor to handle this for you. There's no upside to processing credit cards yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle credit cards transactions with drupal or any other technology you need to comply to the [Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI DSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Piskvor. If you're not 100% sure what you're doing, I think you're better off using existing code that has been tried and tested by the community. Have a look at [Pay module](http://drupal.org/project/pay).